# LibGDX AssetManager not loading some assets

Tags: java, android, libgdx, textures

I have never been more confused in my entire life.

I am developing an app in LibGDX and I have managed to succesfully load a Texture Atlas for a button skin. The problem is, when I tried loading other Texture Atlases, it tells me that it can't load the depencies of the png files of the others!

Here are the atlases I am trying to load:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/3j44xl83otwof4z/Photos.zip

Am I missing something?

EDIT:

Here is the load void in my AssetLoader class:

```
public void load(){
    manager.load("antoanimation.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("textures/bg2.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("bottomtube2.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("clickme.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("diamtermopan.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("gameover.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("grass.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("logo.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("pauseButton.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    manager.load("pausemenu.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("play.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("restartButton.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    manager.load("return.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("selected.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("shopButton.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
    manager.load("textures/shopLayout.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("vladanimation.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("toptube2.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("andreuanimation.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("axelanimation.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("faces.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("themes.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("boop.wav", Sound.class);
    manager.load("failed.wav", Music.class);
    manager.load("wow.wav", Sound.class);
    manager.load("ding.wav", Sound.class);
    manager.load("resumeButton.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    manager.load("tomhanks.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("alpacaanimation.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("crevete.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("victoranimation.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("claw machine.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("coin.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("tudoranimation.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("menuButton.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
```

Comment: show your code how you're trying to load ?

Comment: Edited the post with the code

Comment: Can you post the error message please?

Comment: Wow, for some reason, it's not giving me the error anymore! It just needed a restart

Comment: May have just needed a refresh to let your IDE know the resources were there.